# AWS solution for data transfers between Amazon MQ and Amazon MSK

Tags: aws-msk, amazon-mq

What is the AWS solution I need to setup to transfer data between an Amazon MQ (RabbitMQ) queue and a topic on Amazon MSK cluster. Both in the same availability zone.